# How does the proc in the caches_action if clause get execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, lambda

I have a newbie kind of question which I can't get my head around. How is the Proc in the if condition get executed for the `caches_action` method.

For example:

```
caches_action :show, :if=>Proc.new{|x| something}
```

What I don't get is how this gets called.
I know I can execute a proc defined as

`proc= Proc.new` by
`proc.call`

so I don't understand how this gets called.

Second, how do I pass conditions like

`if logged_in?`

I'd appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 5):

The parameter pass on Proc is the current object. So in your example it's the `x` variable. So you can call all method of this instance. If you want call the `logged_in?` method. You can because it's a public instance

```
caches_action :show, :if => Proc.new{|x| x.logged_in? }
```

The proc is call before the filter. A caches_action is like a before_filter. This filter check if there are already a cache about this action or not. Unless, the cache is generate.

With the `:if` the filter is call only if the if is call. So the proc is call. If you don't use a Proc, the `:if` value is interpret only during the file reading on the server starting.

Comment: Thanks for response. What I would also like to know is what invokes the Proc or how does this get called. Is there some internal method that does a Proc.new.call kind of operation. I dont really follow how it gets called.

Answer (score 0):

`:if => proc { logged_in? }`

My understanding is that you're sending it a block to evaluate. So you if you have a method in a helper or in the controller logged_in, it will call that and evaluate. I believe it's the controller class that is calling the proc.

From documentation; "If a block is given, it is called with the current controller instance."

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html